# Finding related keywords for low-volume keywords

Tags: seo, google, keywords

Being able to find search keywords that are related to a certain keyword is very important for me. For example, say that I want to know if there's a market for **nose-scratching software**. Then I can look for how often this keyword gets searched using AdWords keyword planner, and say that I find there are only 100 monthly searches. Okay.

But then, maybe most people who need nose-scratching software actually search for **software to scratch my nose**, which isn't picked up by my previous keyword. I want to know about this related keyword.

Now, I could use Google Trends for that, as it shows related keywords just like that; the problem is that Google Trends doesn't show related keywords for keywords with too low search volume, like nose-scratching software. These searches are still be lucrative for niche needs despite being low-volume, so I really want to find related keywords for them.

**Does anyone have an idea how to get related keywords for low-volume keywords?**

Comment: Really, there is nothing I have found that does this except one- using the Google search textbox and entering various different forms of queries and paying attention to Google auto-suggest. The other thing you can do is to look at other websites. Still, sometimes you just have to spend sometime thinking like a user. I found some powerful ranking opportunities that I could not get anywhere else by imagining I was a user. Unfortunately, this is not something that can be automated or automated easily. Computers do not have imaginations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a tool that will automate what closetnoc suggested, using Google Auto suggest.

[Keyword Tool](http://keywordtool.io/)

Type in a keyword and it will give you all the related Google Auto suggests, which are based on what people are searching for.